# Is there a Linq to Entities debug Visualizer working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, visualizer

I found [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/99468ece-689b-481c-868c-19e00e0a4e69/view/Reviews) but this is not working for me.I added a reference and also tried to also copy it to this directory -\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers
Has anyone tried using this or something similiar that helps me see the sql code generated by Linq query.I know I can use the profiler but I want something more easier and quick and this visualizer i thought would be the best... I am using vs2010 and .net 4.0 any ideas ?

Comment: Not exactly a debug visualizer but a query profiler that ties queries to the code that generated/executed them: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/06/entity-framework-support-in-huagati.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly visit the Q&A section in [http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/99468ece-689b-481c-868c-19e00e0a4e69].  There are steps to get this visualizer working.
Today i've released the WPF version of the visualizer where you can add/edit linq query parameters and also export the query results to Excel.

To learn more on how to use the tool kindly visit my website.  Further there are few blogs like http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Entity-Visualizer explaining how to get it working.

Two main items to get it working are

1. Download to correct folder and using the properties window in Windows Explorer unblock to use internet downloaded files.
2. Add  in devenv.exe.config file.

For WPF version you'll have two dlls.